# pandas/matplotlib graph on frequency of appearance

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I am a pandas newbie and I want to make a graph from a CSV I have. On this csv, there's some date written to it, and I want to make a graph of how frequent those date appears.
This is how it looks :

```
2022-01-12
2022-01-12
2022-01-12
2022-01-13
2022-01-13
2022-01-14
```

Here, we can see that I have three records on the 12th of january, 2 records the 13th and only one records the 14th. So we should see a decrease on the graph.
So, I tried converting my csv like this :

```
date,records
2022-01-12,3
2022-01-13,2
2022-01-14,1
```

And then make a graph with the date as the x axis and the records amount as the y axis.
But is there a way panda (or matplotlib I never understand which one to use) can make a graph based on the frequency of appearance, so that I don't have to convert the csv before ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function of PANDAS which allows you to count the number of values.

First off, you'd need to read your csv file into a dataframe. Do this by using:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("~csv file name~")
```

Using the unique() function in the pandas library, you can display all of the unique values. The syntax should look like:

```
uniqueVals = df("~column name~").unique()
```

That should return a list of all the unique values. Then what you'll do is use the function value_counts() with whatever value you are trying to count in square brackets after the normal brackets. The syntax should look something like this:

```
totalOfVals = []

for date in uniqueVals:

    numDate = df[date].valuecounts("~Whatever date you're looking for~")
    totalOfVals.append(numDate)
```

Then you can use the two arrays you have for the unique dates and the amount of dates there are to then use matplotlib to create a graph.

You'll want to use the syntax:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

mpl.plot(uniqueVals, totalOfVals, color = "~whatever colour you want the line to be~", marker = "~whatever you want the marker to look like~")
mpl.xlabel('Date')
mpl.ylabel('Number of occurrences')
mpl.title('Number of occurrences of dates')
mpl.grid(True)
mpl.show()
```

And that should display a graph with all the dates and number of occurrences with a grid behind it. Of course if you don't want the grid just either set mpl.grid to False or just get rid of it.

Comment: this is great, thank you. But I have one question, `uniqueVals = df("~column name~").unique()` is going to delete all duplicates. So I won't be able to count the frequency if I only have unique values.

Comment: It won't make a difference as you are counting the occurrences out of the original dataframe not out of the array of unique values, it's just using that as a counter so you are not counting more than you need to